# Unable to delete associated entity fetched using query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am not able to delete associated entity instance fetched using query, I have following classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private int personId;
    @Column(name = "PERSON_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String personName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private DrivingLicense drivingLicense;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DRIVING_LICENSE")
public class DrivingLicense {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "LICENSE_NUMBER")
    private int licenseNumber;
    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_ISSUE")
    private Date dateOfIssue;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
}
```

and I am trying to delete like

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

List<Person> resultList = entityManager.createQuery("from Person p join fetch p.drivingLicense", Person.class).getResultList();
resultList.forEach(person -> System.out.println(person.getDrivingLicense().getDateOfIssue()));

DrivingLicense drivingLicense = resultList.get(0).getDrivingLicense();
System.out.println(drivingLicense.getLicenseNumber());
entityManager.remove(drivingLicense);


entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I assumed that it will delete DrivingLicense, but ts not deleting it. And when I tried to remove Person by using `entityManager.remove(resultList.get(0))` then it removed the person along with DrivingLicense.

I am getting how it works? And why DrivingLIcense is not getting deleted?

Comment: I got the reason for it. it wasn't getting deleted cause the Person reference is still referring to the DrivingLicense Reference which was not letting it deleted, so when the reference was made null it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you are getting referential integrity constraint error, as you did not update the other side of the bi-directional association.

Try updating the references before removal of entity:

```
Person person = resultList.get(0);
DrivingLicense drivingLicense = person.getDrivingLicense();
drivingLicense.setPerson(null);
person.setDrivingLicense(null);
entityManager.merge(person);
entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(drivingLicense));
```

Comment: you're right! that was the only reason, I have also updated it in my comments.

Comment: ah! you commented just before I posted the answer :) anyway, glad it's working now.